# printing Java hotspot JIT assembly code

Tags: java, assembly, jit, disassembly, jvm-hotspot

I wrote a very stupid test class in Java:

```
public class Vector3 {
   public double x,y,z ;

   public Vector3(double x, double y, double z) {
       this.x=x ; this.y=y ; this.z=z ;
   }

   public Vector3 subst(Vector3 v) {
      return new Vector3(x-v.x,y-v.y,z-v.z) ;
   }
}
```

Then I wanted to see the code generated by the Java Hotspot JIT (Client VM build 23.7-b01). I used the "-XX:+PrintAssembly" option and the hsdis-i386.dll from http://classparser.blogspot.dk/2010/03/hsdis-i386dll.html

Here is the interesting part of the generated code (I have skipped the initialization of the new object. EDIT: the code for the subst method). Obviously, ebx is the "this" pointer and edx is the pointer to the argument.

```
lds    edi,(bad)
sti    
adc    BYTE PTR [ebx+8],al  ;*getfield x
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+56]
lds    edi,(bad)          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x02611f2d
sti    
adc    BYTE PTR [edx+8],cl  ;*getfield x
lds    edi,(bad)
sti    
adc    BYTE PTR [ebx+16],dl  ;*getfield y
lds    edi,(bad)
sti    
adc    BYTE PTR [edx+16],bl  ;*getfield y
lds    edi,(bad)
sti    
adc    BYTE PTR [ebx+24],ah  ;*getfield z
lds    edi,(bad)
sti    
adc    BYTE PTR [edx+24],ch  ;*getfield z
lds    edi,(bad)
sti    
pop    esp
rol    ebp,0xfb
adc    DWORD PTR [eax+8],eax  ;*putfield x
lds    ebp,(bad)
jmp    0x02611f66
rol    ebp,cl
sti    
adc    DWORD PTR [eax+16],edx  ;*putfield y
lds    ebx,(bad)
fistp  DWORD PTR [ebp-59]
sti    
adc    DWORD PTR [eax+24],esp  ;*putfield z
```

Honestly, I am not very familar with x86 assembly but does that code make sense to you? What are those strange instructions like "adc BYTE PTR [edx+8],cl" doing? I would have expected some FPU instructions.

Comment: You might get better answers if you tag your question `assembly`.

Comment: To me, this assembly code makes no sense. I doubt this is the actual executable code generated by HotSpot.

Comment: I suspect that your disassembler is unable to interpret the machine code correctly. The opcode for `LDS` is `0xc5`, but that could also be a [2-byte VEX prefix](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#VEX.2FXOP_opcodes) on newer x86 CPUs.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The conclusion seems to be that the disassembler used in the dll is not correctly decoding the generated code. I will try to build the dll myself, following the instructions at http://dropzone.nfshost.com/hsdis.htm

Comment: Please make an answer of the solution you found yourself and accept it, so that people can immediately see that this question is solved. It will help others who might encounter similar kind of problems.

Answer (score 6):

Me again. I have built the hsdis-i386.dll using the latest binutils 2.23. It was easier than I expected thanks to the instructions in http://dropzone.nfshost.com/hsdis.htm
(at least for the x86 version. The 64-bit version compiles but stops the JVM immediately without any error message)

The output now looks much better:

```
vmovsd xmm0,QWORD PTR [ebx+0x8]  ;*getfield x
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x40]
vmovsd xmm1,QWORD PTR [edx+0x8]  ;*getfield x
vmovsd xmm2,QWORD PTR [ebx+0x10] ;*getfield y
vmovsd xmm3,QWORD PTR [edx+0x10] ;*getfield y
vmovsd xmm4,QWORD PTR [ebx+0x18] ;*getfield z
vmovsd xmm5,QWORD PTR [edx+0x18] ;*getfield z
vsubsd xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
vmovsd QWORD PTR [eax+0x8],xmm0  ;*putfield x
vsubsd xmm2,xmm2,xmm3
vmovsd QWORD PTR [eax+0x10],xmm2 ;*putfield y
vsubsd xmm4,xmm4,xmm5
vmovsd QWORD PTR [eax+0x18],xmm4 ;*putfield z
```

Comment: That looks *a lot* more plausible (+1)

Comment: Indeed :) I have programmed a simple raytracer and it is nice to see how the JIT works thanks to this feature. Classes like Vector3 are completely inlined since they have no subclasses. The SSE2 extensions are used as a kind of "super FPU". Something a little bit disappointing: in the constructor of Vector3, the JIT code always first sets this.x,this.y,this.z to 0.0, even in "new Vector3(x-v.x,y-v.y,z-v.z)". Three unneeded memory accesses of 8 bytes each.